# Javascript Navigate elements to nearest input or select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JavaScript function that grabs the div container with the class "form-row".

The HTML below is a simplified version, but is the same structure as the nested elements i'm using.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label></label>
    <div class="content">
        <input></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to grab the input within this container, and i'm having trouble doing so.

I've tried the following :-

```
var x = item.Next('input');

x.prop("checked",false);
```

But its not working.

How can i traverse the elements until i reach the input ans set its properties.

I only want to look at elements within this container.

Comment: item is a javascript object that has represents the div with class "form-row"

Comment: Then `item.find('input');` will work

Comment: FYI, `input` is void element, it cannot contains any content and so doesn't have any closing tag. BTW, by default, `input` type is text, it cannot be checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*item is a javascript object that has represents the div with class "form-row"*, you need [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
var x = item.find('input');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick `$('.form-row').find('input').prop('checked', 'checked')`